# OneHotEncoding 2500 different categorical variables

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, classification, one-hot-encoding, multilabel-classification

I am working on a flight recommendation project where airport codes of each source will be given along with some data. with that i have to predict the destination to which airplane can reach.

I have to deal with 6+ million rows. so I am facing a problem while oneHotEncoding airport codes, (which in the present dataset are more than 3000). before fitting it into a model.
Can anyone suggest how to onehotencode or deal with this kind of problem?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
onehotencoder1 = OneHotEncoder()
onehotencoder1.fit(X)
X = onehotencoder1.transform(X)
```

and i am getting can't allocate 11.3 Gib.

I tried for less data and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `pandas`? It has a a similar `get_dummies` function which may work.